# Стили для карточек товаров на php

Tags: css

Реализовал в каталоге вывод карточек товаров, но когда добавлю, они слипаются, я не могу понять из-за чего. Очень долго не могу решить этот вопрос

```
<section id="product1" class="section-p1">
  <ul id="navbar" class="categorynav">
    <li><a href = "#">Инструменты</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Запчаcти</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Строй материалы</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#">Сантехника</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="pro-container">
    <?php foreach($products as $product):  ?>
        <div class="pro" onclick="window.location.href='sproduct.html';">
          <img src="
          <?php
          foreach(explode(',', $product['img']) as $ing)
          echo $ing;
    
          ?>
          " alt="no picture">
            <div class="des">
              <span>MAKITA</span>
              <h5><?php foreach(explode(',', $product['nazvanie']) as $ing) 
              echo $ing;
    endforeach;
              ?>
            </h5>
              <h4>3999р</h4>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
        </div>

        

  </section>
```

Код выводящий из бд
И вот код стилей

```
#product1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#product1 .pro {
  width: 23%;
  min-width: 230px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  margin: 15px 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  position: relative;
}

#product1 .pro:hover {
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

#product1 .pro img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro .des {
  text-align: start;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#product1 .pro .des span {
  color: #060606;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#product1 .pro .des h5 {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#product1 .pro .des h4 {
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #088178;
}

#product1 .pro .cart {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #e8f6ea;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #088178;
  border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

}[image: В итоге так все выглядит]

Comment: CтОит в вопрос добавить чистый html, который в браузере....... php здесь не имеет смысла

Comment: хотя нет........ что это за странная конструкция `<img src="<?php  foreach(explode(',', $product['img']) as $ing)`  ???

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да хрен с ним с этой конструкцией (она странная, но скорее всего выведет слово, что не ломает разметку). Тут скорее вопрос нужно задать: а где второй закрывающий `endforeach;`, который явно должен быть ДО последнего `</div>`?